# Tkinker listbox bind does not seem to work

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm launching a simple dialog from a console script to show a list of items, which should be closed one a list element is double-clicked. I'm hiding the root, and waiting for the action to go on with the script. Nevertheless, nothing happens when I double-click list elements, despite some messages should get printed in console.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class SelectionList:
    def __init__(self, list_of_options):
        root = tk.Tk()
        self.top = tk.Toplevel(root)
        root.withdraw()
        self.selection = None
        self.initialize(list_of_options)
        root.wait_window(self.top)

    def initialize(self, list_of_options):
        frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.top, text='Select an option')
        frame.grid(
            row=0, columnspan=1, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self.top, width=25, height=10)
        self.listbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)
        for opt in list_of_options:
            self.listbox.insert(tk.END, opt)
        self.listbox.bind('<Double-1>', self.selection)

    def selection(self):
        print 'Hello world'
        self.selection = self.listbox.get(self.listbox.curselection()[0])
        print self.selection
        self.quit()
```

Any idea?

EDIT: Based on gill's answer, I edited my code:

- Now the method is called _get_selection to avoid conflicts with self.selection variable. The method also receives an event, even if I don't use it
- I call the mainloop, and removed the Toplevel. The class now inherits from Tkinker.Tk, so it has a quit method implemented.

Nevertheless, it still does not work. The dialog shows up, but nothing gets printed in console when I double click (not even an error).
What am I missing?

Code:

```
import Tkinter as tk


class SelectionList(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, list_of_options):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, None)
        self.title('Select an option')
        self.selection = None
        self.initialize(list_of_options)

    def initialize(self, list_of_options):
        frame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text='Select an option')
        frame.grid(
            row=0, columnspan=1, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self, width=25, height=10)
        self.listbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)
        for opt in list_of_options:
            self.listbox.insert(tk.END, opt)
        self.listbox.bind('<Double-1>', lambda ev: self._get_selection)

    def _get_selection(self, event):
        print 'Hello world'
        self.selection = self.listbox.get(self.listbox.curselection())
        print self.selection
        self.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_of_options = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    dialog = SelectionList(list_of_options)
    dialog.mainloop()
    print 'Selected: ' + str(dialog.selection)
```

Comment: There is something wrong with the indentation of your code.

Comment: Where is the code for `self.quit()`?

Comment: You aren't calling `mainloop()`.

Comment: @BryanOakley nothing wrong, just out of mouse batteries and unable to copy correctly with my laptop trackpad. I'm creating an instance of SelectionList within a script. Do I still need to call mainloop? Where and why?

Comment: Indentation is critical when asking questions about python. If you're not willing to take the time to format it properly, how can you expect us to understand how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems.

1) You defined `self.selection` **twice** (or maybe three times, depending how you count). There is a method called `selection`. Then in `__init__` there is an attribute of the same name, set to `None` (which then gets reset in the method `selection`...). In fact the method is shadowed by the attribute, so when you `bind` the listbox to `self.selection`, you are binding it to `None`, and so when you double click you will get a `TypeError`, if you are paying attention to the console.

As far as I can tell, the attribute `selection` isn't doing any work for you. Just remove it.  And `self.selection` in the body of the `selection` method should be renamed to something else. If you don't need to remember the selected items, use a local variable:

```
selection = self.listbox.get(self.listbox.curselection()[0])
print(selection)
```

After that's done:

2) A function bound to a widget must take an event argument. Your `selection` method does not take that (it takes `self` as the first argument and has no room for other arguments). So you need to either change the signature of `selection` or change the function you bind. To do the latter:

```
self.listbox.bind('<Double-1>', lambda e: self.selection())
```

3) `self.quit` is not defined. Either define it, or remove it.

**PS.**

@BryanOakley has a point when he says that you should call `root.mainloop()`. It's true that `Toplevel` will automatically call its own equivalent of `mainloop` as it were, but organizing your code like this will surprise people, [which is not good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). A more conventional organization would be like this:

```
class SelectionList:
    def __init__(self, master, list_of_options):
        self.top = tk.Frame(master)
        self.top.pack()
        self.initialize(list_of_options)
        # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    SelectionList(root, ['foo', 'bar'])
    root.mainloop()
    # You do not need wait_window for what you do
```

---

EDIT:

There was a fatal typo in my original answer:

```
self.listbox.bind('<Double-1>', lambda e: self.selection)
```

will not call `self.selection()` on double click. It should have been

```
self.listbox.bind('<Double-1>', lambda e: self.selection())
```

Without `()` it's like calling `bar()` in the following code. `foo()` will not get called and nothing will get printed.

```
def foo():
    print('foo')

def bar():
    foo   # should be foo()
```

And to flesh out the other alternative: if you want to avoid `lambda` you can simply add an event argument to `self.selection` (now `self._get_selection` in your edited question, but I'll continue with the old version here). In your case the event argument will not be used, but that's fine.

```
def selection(self, event):
    # no change to the rest
```

And the binding can be simply (this time without `()`):

```
self.listbox.bind('<Double-1>', self.selection)
```

Comment: There's also the problem that `mainloop()` is never called, so the code can't process events.

Comment: @BryanOakley For reasons I myself don't understand, OP's code will actually run without calling `mainloop()`. I can't test it with python 2 now (which is what OP uses), but on 3.4 and 3.5, a listbox will appear if you just instantiate a `SelectionList`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Well, I think I know now. It's because OP uses `Toplevel`, which doesn't need `mainloop()` to start a loop.

Comment: they are creating the root window. I'm assuming it's the only root window, otherwise there would be no need to create it.

Comment: @BryanOakley I'm not sure I totally understand your last remark... but you can just try it: `import Tkinter as tk; tk.Toplevel()`. You will have two windows, one root, one `Toplevel`. OP's way is unusual to be sure, and I guess I should say that in my answer. But it does work.

Comment: @gill I used two windows because I didn't find the way of using only the root. I have edited my question with your advices, but still doesn't work

Comment: @RomanRdgz My bad. I forgot a pair of `()`. It should be `... lambda e: self.selection()` (or `lambda ev: self._get_selection()` for your current version). Without `()` the method is not called.